# Как работает условие с делением по модулю %?

Tags: php, php7

Изучаю PHP и не могу понять как работает условие с делением по модулю `%`, перед оператором `CONTINUE`, **ПРОСТО НЕ ПОНИМАЮ**, сейчас голову сломаю, вот код:

```
$arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

foreach ($arr as $key){

if ($key % 2){
    continue;
}

echo $key.'</br>';
}
```

Он выводит четные числа, но как проверяется условие я не понимаю, объясните пожалуйста на пальцах,    ведь если **1 % 2** это **1**, в условии в скобках у нас получается **1**?!  И?!, что с этого почему **CONTINUE** срабатывает?? **2%2** это **0** и что с того что в условии **0** ?? почему он будет выводить эту **четную двойку** в браузер ? и тд..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что при приобразовании типа Int в Bool используется следующее правило:
0 - False
1, 2, 3... - True

Когда Вы делите 1 на 2 по модулю, остаток - 1, 1 - True, срабатывает If и continue пропускает код дальше и выполняет следующий цикл

А когда делится 2%2, то остаток - 0, 0 - False, if не срабатывает, выводится результат в браузер

Comment: Спасибо большое вам!